# Use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Person')

Tags: c++, error-handling, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person{
public:
    string name;
    int age, height, weight;
public:
    Person(string name = "empty", int age = 0, int height = 0, int weight = 0) {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
        this->height = height;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream os, const Person& p)
{
    os << p.name << "\n" << p.age << "\n" << p.height << "\n" << p.weight << "\n\n";
    return os;
}

class Node {
public:
    Person* data;
    Node* next;
    Node(Person*A) {
        data = A;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node * head;
    LinkedList() {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    void InsertAtHead(Person*A) {
        Node* node = new Node(A);
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }

    void Print() {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            cout << *(temp->data) << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList* list = new LinkedList();

    list->InsertAtHead(new Person("Bob", 22, 145, 70));                 list->Print();
}
```

Hello, I am new to C++ and this is the first time I am overloading an operator. I have done extensive research on how to do so and I do not think my flaw is with the ostream overload. I am aware that there are similar questions, but I cannot seem to get mine to work with the overload I made. Basically my goal is to be able to call the Print function in order to print out the linked list. I believe the issue is on the line "cout << *(temp->data) << " ";" but I am not sure and even if it is I do not know how to go about fixing it. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? The title of the question is an error I am receiving on the line that I posted above which is why I am lead to believe something must be changed there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your `ostream& operator<<(ostream os, const Person& p)` is missing a `&` after the second `ostream`.

Comment: @super wow its always the dumb mistakes.. thanks I would have missed that for so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the stream into the overloaded `<<` operator by reference. You want to do that since you are modifying the stream that was used as the argument. This generates an error since `ostream`s can't be copied.

Correct declaration: `ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Person& p)`